# Javascript event redirecting to another page instead of displaying result in same page

Tags: javascript, html, visualforce

In this piece of code there is a search bar, when I am searching something it will narrow down my search. I am using **onkeyup** event which call javascript function to search the required data, but after entering some text in search bar when i press enter it is redirecting to the home page instead of display the results.

**CODE**

```
<apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
  <apex:param name="Name" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <!--     style="font-weight:bold;">Defect Name<br/> -->
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="Name" onkeyup="doSearch();" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dude, seriously... do you honestly think you've given us sufficient information to help you? No code, unspecific question...

Comment: Hi, add your javascript code to understand what you are trying to communicate. So that we can understand your issue and can solve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the form is submitted on Enter button press.
If you have `<apex:form` tag then try putting `onsubmit="return false;"` there.

```
<apex:form onsubmit="return false;"
```